Does the coherence of light sources make a difference in exciting fluorescence?
Using LED vs laser as light sources in wide-field epi-fluorescence microscopy are both popular choices. It seems that high intensity single color LEDs (such as this one) emits high radiometric power continuously (1W) with a tiny footprint (i.e. resembling an ideal point source and efficient to collimate) and fairly narrow bandwidth. Compact lasers, on the other hand, shoots something like 100mW.
Which one achieves higher intensity in long exposure (~1 second), high-pass wide-field fluorescence microscopy? Does lasers' coherence make a difference in this application?

The emission region of a laser diode is usually orders of magnitude smaller than that of an LED, so if you want the most intensity in the smallest possible focal spot, then the laser should win by large margins. So much so that it will most likely destroy your samples in fractions of a second if you really try to exploit it.
